# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting

Tags: oracle, triggers

i'd encountered following error when creating the following trigger. How to resolve the error? Please..

> Error at line 6: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:
>       ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
>       null pragma raise return select update while with

```
create or replace trigger totalclaimtrig2
after insert on userinfo
for each row
begin
if (:new.sgaji>'2323.41') and (:new.power>1400)  then
(
:new.jumlah_claim := :new.jarak*0.7;
:new.kelas='A';
)

elsif (:new.sgaji>'2323.41') and (:new.power between 1000 and 1400)  then
(
:new.jumlah_claim := :new.jarak*0.6;
:new.kelas='B';
)

elsif (:new.sgaji>'2323.41') and (:new.power between 500 and 1000)  then
(
:new.jumlah_claim := :new.jarak*0.5;
:new.kelas='C';
)

elsif (:new.sgaji>'2323.41') and (:new.power between 175 and 500)  then
(
:new.jumlah_claim := :new.jarak*0.45;
:new.kelas='D';
)

elsif (:new.sgaji>'2323.41') and (:new.power<175)  then
(
:new.jumlah_claim := :new.jarak*0.4;
:new.kelas='E';
)

end if;
end;​
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, you don't use parens to block code in PL/SQL.  You use BEGIN/END blocks.  My suggestion to you is to read some tutorials on PL/SQL first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all parentheses, use `:=` instead of `=` for assignments, remove the weird character after the last `;`, and change `after insert` to `before insert` to change the NEW values.

```
create or replace trigger totalclaimtrig2
before insert on userinfo
for each row
begin
    if :new.sgaji>'2323.41' and :new.power>1400 then
        :new.jumlah_claim := :new.jarak*0.7;
        :new.kelas:='A';
    elsif :new.sgaji>'2323.41' and :new.power between 1000 and 1400 then
        :new.jumlah_claim := :new.jarak*0.6;
        :new.kelas:='B';
    elsif :new.sgaji>'2323.41' and :new.power between 500 and 1000 then
        :new.jumlah_claim := :new.jarak*0.5;
        :new.kelas:='C';
    elsif :new.sgaji>'2323.41' and :new.power between 175 and 500  then
        :new.jumlah_claim := :new.jarak*0.45;
        :new.kelas:='D';
    elsif :new.sgaji>'2323.41' and :new.power<175 then
        :new.jumlah_claim := :new.jarak*0.4;
        :new.kelas:='E';
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: thanks alot.. your answer really helpful.. so i just can proceed to add more constraint in the trigger?

Comment: thanks alot.. your answer really helpful.. what if i want to 'after insert' instead of 'before insert'?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to add more `elsif` blocks.  This can't be done as an `after insert`, because then the rows already exist and there's no way to change the `:new` values.